# Kafka producer with Async not returning DeliveryReport but DeliveryResult

Tags: .net, kafka-producer-api, confluent-kafka-dotnet

I am trying to write messages into Kafka and below is my producer where if i use **produce** it has DeliveryHandler and i could access DeliveryReport, but when i use **ProduceAsync** then the return type is deliveryResult how do i get DeliveryReport and log the reason for failure

Using Produce:

```
    public void WriteMessage(string message)
    {
        using (var producer = new ProducerBuilder<string, string>(this._config).Build())
        {
            producer.Produce(this._topicName, new Message<string, string>()
            {
                Key = rand.Next(5).ToString(),
                Value = message
            },
            (deliveryReport) =>
            {
                if (deliveryReport.Error.Code != ErrorCode.NoError)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Failed to deliver message: {deliveryReport.Error.Reason}");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"KAFKA => Delivered '{deliveryReport.Value}' to '{deliveryReport.TopicPartitionOffset}'");
                }
            });

            producer.Flush(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        }
    }
```

In above code I could get access to DeliveryReport which is inheriting DeliveryResult and could get access to Error Reason & DeliveryResult --> TopicPartitionOffset both, and below is the metadata:

```
namespace Confluent.Kafka
{
    //
    // Summary:
    //     The result of a produce request.
    public class DeliveryReport<TKey, TValue> : DeliveryResult<TKey, TValue>
    {
        public DeliveryReport();

        //
        // Summary:
        //     An error (or NoError) associated with the message.
        public Error Error { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The TopicPartitionOffsetError associated with the message.
        public TopicPartitionOffsetError TopicPartitionOffsetError { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Using ProduceAsync

```
    public async Task WriteAysncMessage(string message)
    {
        using (var producer = new ProducerBuilder<string, string>(this._config).Build())
        {

            var deliveryReport = await producer.ProduceAsync(this._topicName, new Message<string, string>()
            {
                Key = rand.Next(5).ToString(),
                Value = message
            });

            
            producer.Flush(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
        }
    }
```

In above method while using ProducerAsync how do i get access to DeliveryReport to log the Error Reason just like Produce, when i do await on ProducerAsync it is returning DeliveryResult but not DeliveryReport

Also, which is good to use Produce or ProduceAsync while writing on to Kafka.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think i got the solution:

```
        using (var producer = new ProducerBuilder<string, string>(this._config).Build())
        {
            try
            {
                var deliveryResult = await producer.ProduceAsync(this._topicName, new Message<string, string>()
                {
                    Key = rand.Next(5).ToString(),
                    Value = message
                });

                Console.WriteLine($"KAFKA => Delivered '{deliveryResult.Value}' to '{deliveryResult.TopicPartitionOffset}'");
            }
            catch (ProduceException<string, string> e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Failed to deliver message: {e.Error.Reason}");
            }
            producer.Flush(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
        }
```